# How to recognize read/writes to a mmap()ed page from my kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, mmap

I want to write a device which tells me whenever a process reads or writes to it, what was read/written and from where. right now I have

```
map_mmap(struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
    if (remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, vma->vm_pgoff,
                        vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start, vma->vm_page_prot)) {
                return -EAGAIN;
    }

    pr_alert("mmapped with start: %x, offset: %x, len: %d", vma->vm_start, vma->vm_pgoff, vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start); 

    return 0;
}
```

And similar methods for reads and writes, so if for example someone writes "bla" to offset 0x1000, and I use dmesg I get "bla was written to address 0x1000".

The problem is, when a process mmap()s my device, I obtain the address the user requested to map, the desired length, etc., but I can't recognize what and when he actually reads or writes to the pages it received.

So if, for example, someone mmaps a page at physical address 0x1000 from my device into the virtual address  (*addr), then writes a byte using

```
addr[3] = 'a';
```

I would obtain something along the lines of

```
'a' was written to address 0x1003.
```

I figured it was possible as I Imagine every read and write should go through my device. But I can't seem to catch it via my .read, .write, .mmap and I don't have any other Idea. If there isn't a trivial solution a creative one might be possible.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks!